# How to apply a layout to all routes in a /pages' subfolder?

Tags: layout, next.js, next-router

I created some routes in the `/pages` **(next.js)** folder and a subfolder `/account`.
I want to apply a layout to all pages located in `/account` subfolder.

How can I do that easily without applying the layout to every single page in `/account` ?

### Example

I want to apply a layout to `profile.js` and `settings.js`.

```
components/
pages/
 - home.js
 - account/
    - profile.js
    - settings.js
...
```

Any suggestion regarding the architecture will be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need to create a custom app and load the `layout` based on the route - use below as an approach.

i.e

```
// pages/_app.js
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import AccountLayout from '../components/Accountlayout'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {

    if (router.pathname.startsWith('/account/')) {

        return (
            <AccountLayout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </AccountLayout>
        )

    }
    return (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

*Optimizations possible...*

In the above code, you can use header footer as common between account and onn-account layouts, say an `GlobalLayout` - eventually it would become something like

```
<GlobalLayout>
<Layout> OR <AccountLayout>
<Component {...pageProps} />
</Layout> or </AccountLayout>
</GlobalLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update for NextJS 13 and above

NextJS team shipped a new type of router called [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router) in version 13.

It's built on React server components and supports **shared layout**, **nested routing** and has lots of other super-useful features !

Check it out : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router